# How to add the an arrary to an array of arrays in Ada?

Tags: ada

if I have a vector of vectors called AA, and I would like to add a vector on AA how can I achieve that? like I would like to `put [1]` `to [[2],[2,3]]` and `get [[1],[2],[2,3]]`. What if I would like to `return [[]]` in Ada. I tried to achieve that when the `array is []`, then I `return [[]]`.

the code for Ada I have is

```
package A is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Natural, Integer);
subtype Vector is A.Vector;
use all type Vector;
   
package AA is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors (Natural, Vector);
subtype Indefinite_Vector is AA.Vector;
use all type Indefinite_Vector;
```

I want to use these type to operate.
Because I want to translate a code in Python Like this:

```
def test(b,c):
    if b == []:
       return [[]]
    else:
       c.append([b[0]])
       return c

b=[1,2,3]
c=[]
d = test(b,c)
print (c)
print (d)
```

The result is `[[1]],[[1]]`

Comment: Your Python won’t do what you say: the first element of `c` should be `b`, not the first element of `b`. And what about `c`’s previous contents? I think you should try posting some code that tries to do what you want, rather than code which just sets up the environment.

Comment: Do you want to solve the problem you state at the start of this post? or do you want to translate the weird code at the bottom? because **they are not the same**. Also, when I said you should try posting some code, I meant Ada code

Answer (score 1):

You should become familiar with [Annex A](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A.html), which describes Ada's standard libraries, specifically for this case [A.18](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18.html), which describes the standard container library, and particularly [A.18.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-2.html), which describes `Ada.Containers.Vectors`. I suspect you're looking for `procedure Insert`, which allows you to add a new element to a vector in a specific location.